# Python read csv file and strip spaces from it

Tags: python

I've created a script that reads a csv file. It looks ok when I run it in Pycharm, however when I mark the output text and click CTRL+C and paste it into Notepad then I get spaces between each letter.

For example when I have the file in Excel then I get this:

```
30.11.2020 09:03    Torbj%C3%B8rn+%3CTorbj%C3%B8rn%3E   SPF+%3CSeksjon+for+Passord+og+Forebygging%3E    Vennligst+endre+passordet+mitt+til+PST%7Bfacb0950fb7a5c537cf7fa68b8894027%7D
```

When I print copy it from Pycharm output I get this:

```
2 0 2 0 - 1 1 - 3 0   0 9 : 0 3 : 5 1    T o r b j % C 3 % B 8 r n   % 3 C T o r b j % C 3 % B 8 r n % 3 E       S P F   % 3 C S e k s j o n   f o r   P a s s o r d   o g   F o r e b y g g i n g % 3 E         V e n n l i g s t   e n d r e   p a s s o r d e t   m i t t   t i l   P S T % 7 B f a c b 0 9 5 0 f b 7 a 5 c 5 3 7 c f 7 f a 6 8 b 8 8 9 4 0 2 7 % 7 D
```

How can I remove the white spaces?

Ive tried to use `line = line.strip()` with no luck.

**My script:**

```
class Day05:
    print('')
    print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Day 05 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
    print('')

    def printDataInLogFile():
        # Header
        print("Datetime\t", end='')
        print("Name\t", end='')
        print("Section\t", end='')
        print("Message")

        # Read and loop line by line
        file1 = open('./log.csv', 'r')
        lines = file1.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            line = line.strip()
            line = line.replace('+', ' ')
            line = line.replace('%C3%A6', 'æ')
            line = line.replace('%C3%B8', 'ø')
            line = line.replace('%C3%A5', 'å')
            line = line.replace('%7B', '{')
            line = line.replace('%7D', '}')
            date = ""
            name = ""
            section = ""
            message = ""

            for i, d in enumerate(line.split(";")):
                if(i == 0):
                    date = d
                elif(i == 1):
                    name = d
                elif(i == 2):
                    section = d
                elif(i == 3):
                    message = d

            # Body
            if(name != ""):
                print(str(date) + "\t", end='')
                print(str(name) + "\t\t", end='')
                print(str(section) + "\t\t", end='')
                print(str(message))


    """ Script start """
    printDataInLogFile()
```

**Some line with content of log.csv:**

```
2020-10-01 07:00:04;Lisbeth+%3CLisbeth%3E;SPF+%3CSeksjon+for+Passord+og+Forebygging%3E;I+dag+har+jeg+lyst+til+at+PST%7Bb53250c991675c7b0c712e9bdc2c1216%7D+skal+v%C3%A6re+passordet+mitt
2020-10-01 07:02:22;Unni+%3CUnni%3E;SPF+%3CSeksjon+for+Passord+og+Forebygging%3E;Vennligst+endre+passordet+mitt+til+PST%7B5cdadc1037fa416f7d79186adc55f1ff%7D
2020-10-01 07:03:11;Jan+%3CJan%3E;SPF+%3CSeksjon+for+Passord+og+Forebygging%3E;I+dag+har+jeg+lyst+til+at+PST%7B1241512147283b40bfe8e2eac36ac2dd%7D+skal+v%C3%A6re+passordet+mitt
2020-10-01 07:04:26;Maria+%3CMaria%3E;SPF+%3CSeksjon+for+Passord+og+Forebygging%3E;Vennligst+endre+passordet+mitt+til+PST%7Bca1d9d8d4243c374cb14faa8363bc0dc%7D
2020-10-01 07:06:52;Mellomleder+%3CMellomleder%3E;SPF+%3CSeksjon+for+Passord+og+Forebygging%3E;Bytt+til+PST%7B99e12ae9d06336a7d9c644641388450a%7D
2020-10-01 07:09:00;Robert+%3CRobert%3E;SPF+%3CSeksjon+for+Passord+og+Forebygging%3E;I+dag+har+jeg+lyst+til+at+PST%7Bda52537925c86ac5d5352edd78e10350%7D+skal+v%C3%A6re+passordet+mitt
2020-10-01 07:11:13;H%C3%A5kon+%3CH%C3%A5kon%3E;SPF+%3CSeksjon+for+Passord+og+Forebygging%3E;Vennligst+endre+passordet+mitt+til+PST%7B2a6fa4d619a88882dbcf1df5dff8ff65%7D
2020-10-01 07:11:56;Terje+%3CTerje%3E;SPF+%3CSeksjon+for+Passord+og+Forebygging%3E;Jeg+%C3%B8nsker+%C3%A5+endre+passord+til+PST%7B4970a0cdd3f0eb19e9ec1d7423f26de8%7D
2020-10-01 07:14:33;Anette+%3CAnette%3E;SPF+%3CSeksjon+for+Passord+og+Forebygging%3E;I+dag+har+jeg+lyst+til+at+PST%7B1b956ee14848acccdc150db512b2084d%7D+skal+v%C3%A6re+passordet+mitt
2020-10-01 07:14:51;Daniel+%3CDaniel%3E;SPF+%3CSeksjon+for+Passord+og+Forebygging%3E;Bytt+til+PST%7B80f7c07f7d06bbcd38f3af5c90afe866%7D
2020-10-01 07:15:29;Systemeier+%3CSystemeier%3E;SPF+%3CSeksjon+for+Passord+og+Forebygging%3E;Bytt+til+PST%7Be905beda4ccdfaf8c7b3388d057e37c4%7D
```

Comment: Tomalak: Thank you for the tip. It is however big diffrences between each class. I'm learning python and I'm creating one script each day with diffrent topics.

Comment: Ah I see, carry on then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have the file in Excel then I get this:
>
> ```
> 30.11.2020 09:03
> ```
>
> When I print copy it from Pycharm output I get this:
>
> ```
> 2 0 2 0 - 1 1 - 3 0   0 9
> ```

You've saved the file as Unicode in Excel, but you are not reading the file as Unicode in Python.

```
# Read and loop line by line
with open('./log.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-16-le') as file1:
    for line in file1:
        print(line)
```

Notes

- Use context managers to open files (`with open(...) as f:`) instead of naked `open()` calls.
- Always open text files with an explicitly specified `encoding`. If you don't know the encoding, you need to find out. Trusting in defaults does not work here.
- Use [the `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to read CSV files.
- Use the `urllib` module to [decode URL-encoded values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs), instead of trying to do manual string replacements.

E.g. (for a single input that represents the "value" part in a `key=value` pair):

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

raw_value = "Torbj%C3%B8rn+%3CTorbj%C3%B8rn%3E"
parsed_value = parse_qs(f"temp={raw_value}")            # -> {'temp': ['Torbjørn <Torbjørn>']}
actual_value = parsed_value['temp'][0]                  # -> 'Torbjørn <Torbjørn>'
```

can be turned into a function

```
def decode_url_value(raw_value):
    parsed_value = parse_qs(f"temp={raw_value}")
    return parsed_value['temp'][0]

decode_url_value("Torbj%C3%B8rn+%3CTorbj%C3%B8rn%3E")   # -> 'Torbjørn <Torbjørn>'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the libs `unidecode` and `urllib`, you can easily do this:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
from urllib.parse import unquote

...
file1 = open('./log.csv', 'r')
lines = file1.readlines()
for line in lines:
   line = unidecode(unquote(line))
   line = line.strip()
   line = line.replace('+', ' ')
   # line = line.replace('%C3%A6', 'æ')
   # line = line.replace('%C3%B8', 'ø')
   # line = line.replace('%C3%A5', 'å')
   # line = line.replace('%7B', '{')
   # line = line.replace('%7D', '}')
...
```

You'd no longer need to manually replace special characters yourself.

Answer (score -1):

`str.strip()` only removes leading and ending spaces, in order to remove all space characters, use `str.replace(" ", "")`

Comment: this will strip all spaces. Thats now what the OP wants.